# Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools package did not load correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

Everything about my VS 2013 install appears to be working correctly except when I right click on a table in Server Explorer.  I am trying to use the data tools to view the table, which is in a MS SQL database.  Here is the message VS 2013 pops when I right click:

```
The 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
```

Here are the last few lines of the ActivityLog.xml, btw one of the most cryptic log files I have ever read:

```
1222  Begin package load [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools] {00FEE386-5F9F-4577-99F4-F327FAFC0FB9}  VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.112 
1223 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools] {00FEE386-5F9F-4577-99F4-F327FAFC0FB9} 80131534 VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.641 
1224  Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage {FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}  VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.650 
1225 Warning Unexpected system error mode before loading package [SqlStudio Editor Package] {FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}  VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.650 
1226  Begin package load [SqlStudio Editor Package] {FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}  VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.650 
1227  End package load [SqlStudio Editor Package] {FEF13793-C947-4FB1-B864-C9F0BE9D9CF6}  VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:50.691 
1228 ERROR End package load [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools] {00FEE386-5F9F-4577-99F4-F327FAFC0FB9} 80131534 VisualStudio 2014/02/14 13:50:51.044
```

Here is what I have done to try to solve this problem:

- Disabled all plugins/extensions
- Checked for and applied all updates for all extensions and VS 2013 including Update 1
- Did a full VS 2013 install repair operation

VS 2013 now includes the SSDT tools in VS 2013, so I cannot download and install anything, it is suppose to already be working.  Not unless someone knows of a different trick.

I am out of ideas and I have searched quite extensively about this, most of it applied to VS 2012.  If anyone has any good suggestions, that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you installed anything else, for instance any SQL Server dependencies? I'm wondering if that might have messed SSDT up by installing some incompatible DAC binaries. You could try uninstalling "“Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework” and possibly even the SSDT MSIs ("Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" and "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Build Utilities"), then repair VS2013 to reinstall these. Note that you should ensure the DLLs in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin" are deleted before repairing and they are present after the repair.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, I will try them as soon as I get a chance.  Too bad it takes so long to install/uninstall SQL Server in the first place, not to mention the VS 2013 repair operation.  At the end, its possible nothing will work.  I think you are probably right however, that I do have SQL Server 2012 installed, in a previous attempt to get any of it to work.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to 'Add/Remove Programs' in Control Panel, search for "*Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools*" and repair. 
Worked for me.

Comment: where is this add/remove programs ??@Jen

Comment: @Daniel, I found there 4 program with the similar name like Micr...Tools - enu, Micr...Tools - RUS,Micr...Tools Build Utilities - enu, Micr...Tools build utilities - RUS)) Wtf? is it Normal?

Comment: @DinavAhire, start>apps & features. Or just Control Panel>Programs>Programs and Features

Answer (score 6):

And just in case none of those work, you can go to the **[Download Latest SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)** Microsoft page itself.  It lists out the versions of the tool set for each version of Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After trying the other answers and not resolving the issue, I was able to resolve it by

1. Uninstalling Sql Server Data Tools from the control panel
2. Navigating to Extensions and Updates
3. Go to Updates tab -> Update Visual Studio
4. You should get a prompt to enable optional features, choose SSDT
5. Wait for the long installation process, restart if necassary.

Fixed it for me

Comment: I had to follow this - but I installed the package outside of Visual Studio from the MS web page for the SSDT 2015 package . That fixed it.

Comment: Yes. Same for me. I also didn't download the exe when it gave me a choice to just "run install" or "download exe". I just ran it since downloading it didn't work. (I guess it doesn't mean it couldn't work)

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to reinstall the Sql Server Data Tools, try first to simply restart Visual Studio. On my end this fixed the problem. VS2022

Comment: It works after I restarted VS2022

Answer (score 0):

It is not in VS after 2012. Try this link, install separately

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: SSDT is included in VS2013 and VS2015 - it is built in and updates appear through Extensions and Updates mechanism. You have linked to SSDT-BI which is a separate product that installs the Business Intelligence tools.