# 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools' - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: visual-studio

I am regulary getting the message

> The 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools' package did not load correctly

Here a screenshot of the message

[image]

The logs of `ActivityLog.xml` look like this:

> SetSite failed for package [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools]Source: "mscorlib" Description: Value does not fall within the expected range.
> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.UI.DataPackage.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, String context)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.UI.DataPackage.RegisterSimpleModelLibrary()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.UI.DataPackage.<InitializeAsync>d__88.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)

What `Value`? Where can I find and fix the unexpected `Value`?

Opening the Options for `SQL Server Tools` produces the error

> An error occured loading this property page

Here a screenshot of the message

[image]

**Note:**

- both error messages, do not throw if I start Visual Studio with "Run as administrator"
- already tried to uninstall `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools` with `Visual Studio Installer` and re-install it

Comment: Did you get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781494/microsoft-sql-server-data-tools-package-did-not-load-correctly?

Comment: @GhulamFarid - no I didn't get help, I did find the issue and went through it to the best of my ability, here my finding on the given answers 1) sql server data tools, isn't to be found in control panel, as it seems to be now part of visual studio and as I said I did fully uninstall it and re-install it from the visual studio installer 2) visual studio installer should grab the latest version 3) I only have the version from visual studio to begin with, so it is already the one coming with the extensions 4) restarted visual studio several times 5) again it is part of visual studio's installer

Comment: @RandRandom "Value" is the return value from calling the `DataPackage.ThrowOnFailure(vsObjectManager.RegisterSimpleLibrary(DataPackage._simpleModelLibrary, ref this._libraryCookie), null);`, so it's not that you can "simply" fix it. For some reason, for non-administrative runs, this extension cannot be registered correctly. Some file permission issue?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik - `Some file permission issue?` maybe but what file, any idea? or a place I can look into for further details?

Comment: @RandRandom EventLog? Process Monitor traces (compare administrative vs non-administrative ones)?